# Can I pass a parameter to a SQL Agent job?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, sql-server-agent

I am using SQL Server 2017.

I can call a SQL Agent job named MySQLAgent_Job using the below SQLCMD

```
SQLCMD -E -SMySQLServer -Q "msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'MySQLAgent_Job'"
```

Is it possible to pass in a parameter to MySQLAgent_Job thru this command ?

Something like below:

```
SQLCMD -E -SMySQLServer -Q "msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'MySQLAgent_Job FirstParm'"
```

Thank you

Comment: If you can’t, you could always store values in a table.

Comment: Agent jobs are meant to be run unattended, at which point you can't.

Comment: Try:   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5731/how-to-pass-data-between-sql-server-agent-job-steps/   OR  https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=pass+a+parameter+to+a+SQL+Agent+job